# theme($hook, $variables = array()) and how it works in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

I'm trying to output themed content to a page and I've been trying to read up on the theme() function and how it works. As I understand, it provides a method to generate themed HTML. That's exactly what I want. Now, what I don't understand is how I pass it the HTML or the variables I want so that the HTML is generated. What's the $hook parameter? Is it a .tpl.php file? How do I structure this file so that the HTML is displayed in the content section of the page? Can someone explain the theme() function in a very simple way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to write your own module. In your module you have to define your theme using `hook_theme` function.

```
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return array(
        'your_theme_key' => array(
            'variables' => array(
                'nid' => NULL,
                'title' => NULL
            ),
            'template' => 'your_template_filename', // do not include .tpl.php
            'path' => 'path-to-your-template-file'
        )
    );
}
```

After that you should create file `your_template_filename.tpl.php` in your module's folder and in that file you would have variables `$nid` and `$title` (in this example).
Your template file would be look like:

```
// define your html code using variables provided by theme
<div class="node node-type" id="node-<?php print $nid; ?>">
    <h3><?php print l($title, "node/{$nid}"); ?></h3>
</div>
```

After that you can use your theme in any modules in your site. Should be called like that:

```
$variables = array(
    'nid' => $nid,
    'title' => $title
);
$output = theme('your_theme_key', $variables);
print $output;
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad, I'll give that a try and report back.