# drupal 6 include tpl.php in .module file

Tags: php, drupal

I'm new to drupal and wouldlike to place the html for the content of the module otuput in some template. How ist the right way to do it in the module?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read my answer for Drupal 7 [theme($hook, $variables = array()) and how it works in Drupal 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258494/themehook-variables-array-and-how-it-works-in-drupal-7/8258798#8258798)

In Drupal 6 it's very similar process.