# Calling a custom theme using drupal7

Tags: php, drupal-7

Just created a Drupal7 theme in a bubbles module and added a template bubbles.tpl in a folder template inside the module bubbles. With the following hook, I expect calling the template bubble.tpl and pass some variables.

```
function bubbles_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
  return array(
        'bubbles' => array(
            'variables' => array(
                'name' => "test",
                'description' => "test time being."
            ),
            'template' => 'bubbles',
            'path' => 'template'
        )
    );
}
```

In template.php preprocess hook I call

```
  $variables = array(
    'name' => 1,
    'description' => 2
  );
  $output = theme('bubbles',$variables);
```

The $output is empty. I am new to theming so I cant understand where to start debug. 
I would be glad if someone could help .

Comment: This looks like a PHP issue..  You have call for 4 variables for the bubbles_theme function, but supplied only 2 when you call it. Have you check the php error log?

Comment: `theme('bubbles')` doesn't call `bubbles_theme()`; the arguments passed to a function are not related to the arguments passed to the hook.

Comment: I referred to the accepted answer before implementing the code? Where did I mess up ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258494/themehook-variables-array-and-how-it-works-in-drupal-7

Comment: It worked, the path was not correct